# Как определить класс в функции?

Tags: php, классы

Доброго времени подскажите пожалуйста как правильно определить класс внутри функции?

у меня есть функция которая вызывает API Convertio - оно подключается вот так:

```
include './../convertio-php-master/autoload.php';  
use \Convertio\Convertio;
```

в функции я его подключаю таким образом в начале

```
function conv_send ($id,$file) {
   global $dbconect;


   include './../convertio-php-master/autoload.php';  
   use \Convertio\Convertio;

   ..... Далее сама функция
```

Но мне выдает ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Convertio' not found in ...
```

При этом если я просто в тестовом скрипте подключаю так же библиотек конвертио у меня всё работает, я уверен дело тут в том что я не верно подключаю его в саму функцию, подскажите как это делается правильно?

Comment: Вынесите подключение за пределы функции. Вместо `include` лучше используйте `require_once`.

Comment: @NoSkill за пределы? то есть можно просто где то где запускается функция поставить такое подключение получается? а функция внутри себя увидит его? в плане не надо что то global прописывать?